# "From workspace" Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

Please, I am simulating a dynamic system with some inputs with real data in form of array, For example 1*16 or a matrix of 16*16 dimension stored in Matlab workspace. I have been for a long time trying to use the "From Workspace" block in Simulink.

> Blockquote

My simulation Time is 1:10 
Time Step:0.01

> Blockquote

**My Goal** : is to display the content of my array or matrix element by element during my simulation.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFtvZ.jpg)

Thank you a lot in advance for any valuable answer.

Comment: What about a scope block in your simulink model?

Comment: @Daniel If i well understood your question, i would reply .Yes i have a sinus source and differente matlab function and at the end a scope block that gives me the same source without any damping or attenuation.I loaded before my arrays with a constant but obviosly that was the problem,that is why i need to use the "From workspace"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of manually building the struct like you did, I recommend to use a `timeseries` object. It will fore you to use the right data structure and gives better feedback.

Try

```
%16 timestamps matching your data size, replace with your time infomration
time=0:.1:1.5;
%placeholder for your data
m=rand(1,16);
%create timeseries
ts=timeseries(m,time);
```

To verify in MATLAB that your timeseries does what you want, use:

```
ts.plot(); %won't output anything useful with random data.
```

Then use `ts` in your from Workspace block.

Comment: ,Thank you first of all for your reply ,otherwise i tried to load my array "m" as it shown on the image enclosed. it gives me "Index exceeds matrix dimensions". I made m([1,16],numel(time)) .I am not sure if it is correct ! . Thank you once again Sir.

Comment: What is `m`, your data or your time information? Please put the relevant information into your question, the screenshot is difficult to understand.

Comment: Yes it is my 1*16 array. I tried this :                                              time=1:.1:30;
data=m(:,16);
ts=timeseries(data,time);  My Array "m" is m=[1,1,8,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,8,1,1,1,1,8]

Comment: Is `m` your data **or** time? Yes is not an answer to this question!

Comment: I am sorry. m is my data not time .Sorry for not being clear